# Two macros same worksheet

Tags: excel

I’m a total newbie at this. I’ve got a worksheet with a list of jobs. One of the columns relate to the location eg, London, Manchester. When London is selected, I want that row copied to the London worksheet, and so on.

Also, I’ve got a column to show when the job is completed. So when I select completed, I want that row cut and pasted into the completed worksheet.

Now, after searching, I’ve found the code for both these actions and individually they work. But I’m trying to get them to work together. I’ve tried multiple things from searches I’ve done on here and google but nothing is working.

These are the codes I’ve got that work individually:

```
Private Sub         Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As  Range)
Dim wsUse As Worksheet
Dim wsDc As Worksheet
Dim strdc As String
Application.ScreenUpdating =  False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then     Exit Sub

If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub  ' change 2 to the correct column number

Set wsUse =    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workload   Overview")
Set wsDc =    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Completed")


With wsUse
strdc = Target.Value

If strdc = "Completed" Then
    n = .Rows.Count
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
    wsDc.Range("A" & n).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
    wsDc.Range("A" & n).End(xlUp).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode =  False
    Target.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation =   xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub



Private Sub     Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wsUse As Worksheet
Dim wsDc As Worksheet
Dim strdc As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then         Exit Sub

If Target.Column <> 6 Then   Exit Sub  ' change 2 to the    correct column number

Set wsUse =     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workload Overview")
Set wsDc =     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("London")


With wsUse
strdc = Target.Value

If strdc = "London" Then
    n = .Rows.Count
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
    wsDc.Range("A" & n).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
    wsDc.Range("A" & n).End(xlUp).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
End If

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet_Change` is an event that Excel looks out for and the code should be in a worksheet module (rather than ThisWorkbook or a normal module).
You can only have one `Worksheet_Change` change code in a module - shouldn't compile with it twice as you have.

So you need to combine the two procedures into one.
I've made a couple of assumptions - you set `wsDC` to London.  You were then going to add similar code for Manchester and any other city.  If you can guarantee your selected cities will be the same as the sheet name then use that to find your sheet to paste to.
If column 9 isn't Completed (could be Cancelled, In Progress) then can exit the sub as well.

The only difference between a Completed record and a City record are that the completed ones are deleted, so that can be treated the same way as cities except the last `IF` block that checks whether it needs deleting or not.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 'Turn on error handling.
    
    'You may not need to turn off calculation or screenupdating.
    'Always polite to return it to the setting it was, rather than assuming
    'so remember the setting so can be put back later.
    Dim CalcMethod As Long
    CalcMethod = Application.Calculation
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'This is needed if the row is deleted.
    'Deleting a row is a Change event which will cause this code to fire a second time.
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 9 And Target.Column <> 6 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Value <> "Completed" Then Exit Sub
    
    'Assuming Target value will be the same as the sheet name if column 6,
    'or a "Completed" if it's column 9.
    'e.g. London, Manchester, New York, Completed.
    Dim wsDc As Worksheet
    Set wsDc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Target.Value)
    
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
    wsDc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    wsDc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    
    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Value = "Completed" Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Target.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    
TidyExit:
    'Turn everything back on.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = CalcMethod
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
Exit Sub

'If an error occurs, skip to this section (which is outside the main body),
'deal with the error and jump back into the code so everything can be
'turned back on before exiting.
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
    Resume TidyExit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hang on... something wrong here.  What's `wsUse` used for.  Is that the source sheet?  i.e. Where `Target` is?

Comment: Realised I made an error in the PasteSpecial line.  Have also added some extra code.

Comment: I’m sorry, I have no idea what wsUse is, I’ve just copied and pasted this and got it to work. I don’t understand the codes yet.

Comment: In  your original code is `Set wsUse =    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workload   Overview")`.  I take it _Workload Overview_ is the sheet that's being copied from?

Comment: Yes that’s right. 
I’ve pasted in your code but neither bit is working.

Comment: What do you mean by neither bit?  Is it giving an error message & what line?  Is the code in the _Workload Overview_ sheet module and is it the only bit of code called `Worksheet_Change`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I mean that nothing happens. There’s no errors, just nothing. The code is in the workload overview and there’s no other code anywhere.

Comment: Ok  And it's column 6 (F) & 9 (I)? Set a break point on the `Calc` method by clicking in the margin to the left of the line. The code should pause there if it runs at all.

Comment: If the code doesn't start open the immediate window & type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and try again. If that doesn't work I'm not sure the code is in the right place.

Comment: Thanks very much. I’ll take another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: No I can’t get it to work. In VB editor, I right-clicked ok workload overview and did insert module. Then I pasted your code. There’s no other code anywhere. But nothing happens when i change the city or the completed. No error messages. I’ve tried the last couple of bits you said but still nothing. I think I’ll have to study a bit more to see where I’m going wrong.

Comment: Can workbooks get messed up and remember old code or something? When I deleted all the code and put in one of my original codes (that worked before) it now doesn’t work. If I start a new workbook from scratch, it works. 

Also on a fresh workbook, I put in the code provided above and it worked for the city part, but only once.   All I want is my two working codes merged somehow, I’m not clever enough for this